# Weblogic nodemanager errors/timeout

Tags: weblogic

Running a Windows domain on a NAS, we infrequently see this error. We're worried it may be our configuration causing a problem, possibly some `nodemanager.properties` setting, a WLST call, etc.

Eventually we are unable to command the NodeManager via JMX and WLST. Cycling the NM works but is not a good solution. Is there something else we can try via WLST?

```
<Jan 22, 2015 6:09:28 PM> <SEVERE> <Domain1> <ms1> <Unexpected error while monitoring server>
java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired
        at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.create(FileKey.java:27)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.<init>(FileChannelImpl.java:1037)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.fileLockTable(FileChannelImpl.java:806)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:823)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:860)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.util.ConcurrentLockedFile.read(ConcurrentLockedFile.java:54)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.common.StateInfo.load(StateInfo.java:130)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.AbstractServerMonitor.loadStateInfo(AbstractServerMonitor.java:497)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.AbstractServerMonitor.runMonitor(AbstractServerMonitor.java:273)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.AbstractServerMonitor.run(AbstractServerMonitor.java:246)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerMonitor.run(ServerMonitor.java:25)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired
        at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.init(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.create(FileKey.java:25)
        ... 11 more
```